# Can You Receive Both a Simple IRA and SEP IRA?

Tags: united-states, ira, s-corporation, simple-ira, sep-ira

I am the employee of two companies.  At one company, I receive a SEP IRA.  I know that SEP IRAs are not included in the standard annual elective deferral limit.  At the second company, I have the option to receive a Simple IRA.

Can you receive both a SEP and SIMPLE IRA at the same time?  If so, are there any hard limits on either IRAs or the combined total from the 2 IRAs?

For example, the 2018 limit for Simple IRAs is $12,500.  Does this number go down if I add a SEP IRA into the mix?  Does the characteristics of the SEP IRA change at all if I receive a Simple IRA?